# on run statWeblogic.sh I have a problem with dcevm

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, weblogic, dcevm

I get this error:

> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java: relocation error:
> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/libresource.so: symbol
> JVM_GetManagementExt, version SUNWprivate_1.1 not defined in file
> libjvm.

So with the link-time reference
I don't resolve this issue, anyone help

> My specs: ubuntu 16.04, oracle jdk 1.8.181, weblogic 12c

Comment: https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/147#issuecomment-247767565 and https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/issues/101#issuecomment-862168721 says you may have openjdk or mix jdk installed

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic is not supported by dcevm and I suppose oraclejdk neither. So whether WLS will work on given version of dcevm + oraclejdk is pretty much coincidental. I found that some ancient versions do actually work, see my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70759485/3484881