# Weblogic Server with Hotswap agent

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic12c, jrebel, hotswapagent

We are looking a free alternative for jRebel. It seems hotswap agent is a free good alternative for jRebel. But I didn't sure about it supports weblogic server , is there anyone use hotswap agent with weblogic server and how?

Comment: I am too looking at dcevm/hotswap right now and I am about to experiment with using it on weblogic. I found that in this issue https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/164  it is said that weblogic is not officially supported, so this is a bit discouraging. On the other hand one of commenter submitted some draft for a plugin that adds weblogic support.

Comment: For now my weblogic won't even start with latest jdk8 dcevm version - I get this https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/issues/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DCEVM and HotswapAgent do not support Weblogic. Maintainers are clear about that, it is mentioned in many issues: [here](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/164#issuecomment-450727573), [here](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/164#issuecomment-667647860) and [here](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/issues/98#issuecomment-868340367).

So if you are looking for a solution that will flawlessly work out of the box on WLS, is up-to-date and supported for recent java versions, then I'm afraid DCEVM is not one.

But if your are ok with **unsecure**, **hacky** solution, then read on.

The first problem with dcevm and weblogic is to even get it running. I tested [weblogic docker image](http://image%20https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-weblogic-server-12c) with dcevm + HotswapAgent and most combinations of oraclejdk and dcevm versions cause [error](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/issues/101) or other JVM/WLS crash on startup.
Long time ago the maintainers [said oraclejdk should](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/issues/49) work with dcevm, but I guess this is not actively supported/tested and just works by coincidence on some combination of versions. Deep magic used by WLS doesn't help also.

But thanks to [some comments](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/issues/69) I found WLS will start on these two:

- oraclejdk 1.8.0_05 + dcevm installer-light-jdk8u5.52.jar (25.5-b02-dcevmlight-58)
- oraclejdk 1.8.0_25 + dcevm DCEVM-light-8u45-installer.jar (25.45-b02-dcevmlight-15

**NOTE: These versions are ancient and probably have lots of security vulnerabilities, use at your own risk.**

procedure:

- overwrite original java `/u01/jdk/` in the image,
- take `linux_amd64_compiler2/product/libjvm.so` from dcevm installer and put it in `/u01/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/dcevm`
- add `-XXaltjvm=dcevm` to weblogic commandline.
- (optionally) to get HotswapAgent features:

  - add `hotswap-agent-core.jar` or `hotswap-agent.jar` in `/u01/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/hotswap` together with option `-javaagent:/u01/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/hotswap/hotswap-agent.jar` on wls commandline
  - add `hotswap-agent.properties` to your war/ear/classpath
  - see also https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/pull/418

Now run a remote debugging session, modify a class by adding a new method and recompile - hotswapping new method is not supported by standard hotswap, it will only work when dcevm is active.